# Can Lamb Shoulder Chops be treated the same way as a steak?

Tags: steak, lamb

I am confused about cooking method (dry vs wet heat) and timing of lamb shoulder chops.

According to foodnetwork, lamb shoulder is a tough cut, that is suited for slow cooking like braising, but also from them [Pan-Grilled Lamb Shoulder Chops](https://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/food-network-kitchen/pan-grilled-lamb-shoulder-chops-recipe-3361507) shows that I can cook them similar to a steak?

As for why I am looking at lamb shoulder chops, well, it's half the price of a lamb loin/rib over here.

Comment: That recipe uses a marinade. Could the marinade soften the meat before cooking?

Answer (score 1):

I confirm, I regularly grill lamb chops in a pan (or even better, on a barbecue) and it is delicious! Of course it won't be as soft as a piece of meat that you slow-cooked for hours, but it is not hard either. It should be cooked quickly, 3-4 minuts on each side, I imagine that it will get hard if you overcook them. You can indeed also marinate them before, which will make them more tender and tastier.